# PHP Prepared statement has an issue

Tags: php, mysqli

Me again, more issues that I really can't find the cause off.

The below code is producing: "Issue" which means the first IF statement is false, should be true.

PHP:

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    //Use prepared statements to stop SQL Injection
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, email, password, salt, perms FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT = 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email); //Bind "$email" to paramater
        $stmt->execute(); //Execute the query
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $email, $db_password, $salt, $perms); //get variables from result
        $stmt->fetch();
        $password = hash('sha512', $password.$salt); //hash the password with the unique salt

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) { //If user exists
            //Check that user account isn't locked
            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                //Account is locked, alert user
                return false;
            } else {
                if ($db_password == $password) { //Check that passwords match
                    //matches
                    echo "matches";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "No user found!";  
        }
    } else { 
        echo "Issue";
    }
}
```

$email and $password are not blank, and the $mysqli is the database object. Any ideas? 
I can't figure it out at all, all looks fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really add `mysql` error reporting. It would of told you there was an issue in your query near `LIMIT = 1`.

Query should be:

`SELECT id, email, password, salt, perms FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1`

To add the error reporting, change the `echo "issue";` to be:

```
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
```

Answer (score 3):

`Limit = 1` should be `LIMIT 1`. Here's the `if` corrected :

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, email, password, salt, perms FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1"))
```